# Kubernetes multi-container pod termination process

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, termination

I have a multi-container pod in k8s, let's call them A and B. When stopping the pod, A must stop before B because A needs B until it's off.

To do that, I registered a `preStop` hook on A so A can gracefully stop before B.

However I'm not sure this is a good solution, because I miss some information I can't find in k8s documentation:

What happens when a multi-container pod is stopped?

- All containers `preStop` hooks are called, then when they are all over all containers receive `SIGTERM`, or
- In parallel, all containers receive `preStop` if they have one or directly `SIGTERM` if they don't?

In the second case, `preStop` is useless for what I want to do as B will be instantly killed.

Comment: Should it not be the other way around, B should have a preStop hook to check if a is down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, during pod deletion, the container runtime sends a TERM signal to the main process in each container.

According to [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination):

> 1. If one of the Pod's containers has defined a  `preStop`  [hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks),
>    the kubelet runs that hook inside of the container.
> 2. The kubelet triggers the container runtime to send a TERM signal to process 1 inside each container.

This numeration can confuse - looks like TERM signal will be sent only after `preStop`  hook will be finished.
I decided to check the order of work with a simple example below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: config
    configMap:
      name: nginx-conf
  containers:
  - name: container-1
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sleep","15"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  - name: container-2
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 81
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config
      mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
```

Container-1 has `preStop`  hook for 15 seconds delay.
I've connected to both containers to see behavior during pod deletion.

**Result**

After pod deletion:

1. Container-1 worked for 15 seconds, before the connection was lost
2. Container-2 immediately lost connection

**Conclusion**

If the container has a `preStop`  hook, it will try to execute it. Only then it will receive TERM signal. *The main condition in this case: the grace period has not expired.*

If the container doesn't have a  `preStop`  hook, it will receive TERM signal immediately after the command to remove the pod. Thus, it will not wait while`preStop`  hook will be executed for another container.

> **Note:** The containers in the Pod receive the TERM signal at different times and in an arbitrary order. If the order of shutdowns
> matters, consider using a `preStop` hook to synchronize.

Comment: So I guess if there are dependencies, the best way is to add a preStop with a simple sleep on the container that has to wait for the other, which is longer than the deadline of the other one.